# How are apps ranked differently between GooglePlay search and Category listings

Tags: google-play-store

When I do any search like "games" or "business" in GooglePlay, I get a certain way in which the apps are ranked.

But for some reason, in the category listings, the app are listed in an entirely different order.

Would you know why there is such high discrepancy? And what factors the category listing takes into consideration?

EDIT:

Here is an example:

@Izzy Sure, when I type "business" into GooglePlay search, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.problemio&hl=en) comes up as #5 for me. But when I go through Categories --> business --> free, I have to scroll all the way to #140 to see that app. Why does difference happen?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Maybe you could give an example, so we can understand better? Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy thanks, I just added the example in my original question.

Comment: So you are not talking about ranking in the sense of rating, but rather about the position of the app in the list displayed? That's comparing a category listing versus keyword search. It could simply be the keyword is present more often in that app's description than in others.

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, I am talking about the position in the app store where the app is displayed.

Comment: OK, now that's perfectly clear :) Unfortunately, I don't know the algorithms used by Google. Let's see if someone else does. Good luck!